# Updating Custom Object Properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, updating, custom-properties

I'm tired of looping through an object literal to get its length for one reason or another. I want to define a `length` property onto `Object.prototype`, I can set the initial length, but I don't know how to update it when the object is modified?

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'length', {value: 0});

//  obj.length === 0;

obj.d = 4;

//  obj === {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4};
//  obj.length === 0;
```

Any String/Array object does this automatically, if you know how this happens then please enlighten me, if not then maybe you know a way to update this custom property?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9qpjoLbr/1/ ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the length of the number of keys in an object, use `Object.keys(obj).length`.

If you're crazy and want it on the prototype...

```
Object.prototype.getKeyLength = function() {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
};
```

> Any String/Array object does this automatically, if you know how this happens then please enlighten me...

These are host objects/primitives and it happens behind the covers.

Comment: Ok dude cheers for the heads up on the `keys` method, but `getKeyLength` is a function and therefore needs to be called to update the property... that means I'd have to `ovserve` the object for changes and then call the function

Answer (score 2):

Your init guess is close enough, from [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

You can use use get instead of value, to define a getter, which be called when the defined property is accessed.

A Demo

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'len', {
  writeable: false,
  get: function() {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
  }
});

var a = {
  't' : 'This',
  's' : 'A tsets'
};

console.log(a.len);

a['2222'] = 3;

console.log(a.len);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keylength', {
  get: function getKeyLength() {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
  }
});
```

Comment: cheers dude, but the whole idea is to look at the chrome console when debugging and seeing 50 property values without having to click 50 `(...)` initiators

Comment: It seems you need it only for debugging, if you want to easier in this, you may send a request to Chrome's creator.

Comment: can you elaborate on that, maybe with a bit of code?

Comment: This is the only way in ECMAScript 5 and ECMAScript 6, Chrome show you `(...)` instead of number of properties because it want to display the object faster (by avoid executing property getter/setter). If there was a feature called `onsetproperty`, everything go easier, but sorry, current ECMAScript standard doesn't support.

Comment: Yeah i wish! bring on `Object.onCreated`, and many other Object lifecycle events...